# Delete multiple rows from devexpress gridcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I have a wpf application in which one of the user controls uses a `devexpress` grid control. I have given the user functionality to select a particular row and delete it by handling the `keydown` event as mentioned in the code below:

```
private void m_gridA_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Tableview view = sender as Tableview;
    if(e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        IList<GridCell> celllist = null;
        celllist = (sender as TableView).GetSelectedCells();
        if(cellist.Count < 10)
            return;
        view.DeleteRow(view.FocusedRowHandle)
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine when the user selects a single row. However how do I implement the same functionality if the user needs to delete multiple rows at the same time.

This is the approach I tried:

```
int[] rows = m_gridA.GetSelectedRowHandles();
```

Then loop over each row handle and delete them. The problem with this approach that I am facing is that in my application, there is a lot of data in the grid control. So in order to make sense of the data a lot of filtering is done using the grid control filter editor. Due to this the function `GetSelectedRowHandles` returns the row handles selected and visible in the current filtered view. So when I call `view.DeleteRow(row[i])` it deletes some other row in the grid control whose rowhandle matches that of the grid control in the unfiltered condition.

How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code like this.  It prevents the grid from updating its internal state (including the filter) while you're doing multiple deletes.

```
view.Grid.BeginDataUpdate();
//Delete multiple rows here
view.Grid.EndDataUpdate();
```

Answer (score -1):

```cs
gridView1.BeginUpdate();
Int32[] selectedRowHandles = gridView1.GetSelectedRows();
int t = -1;
foreach(var item in selectedRowHandles) {

    if(item >= 0 && t == -1)
        t = item;
    if(t >= 0)
        gridView1.DeleteRow(t);

}
gridView1.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: A little more information wouldn't hurt. This solution also seems to only delete one row since `t` will never be `-1` a second time.